# Determining a velocity value using energy conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation

The idea is to create an experiment that'll give you the initial velocity value with which you throw a ball down at 1 meter so it bounces to 2 meters.

I don't have a solid Coefficient of Restitution to use, however. I can determine time and the like and use a kinematic equation, but how would I utilize energy conservation in this case? I get to 
$$v_f = \sqrt{2gh_i+v_1^2} $$
and can't get out of the rut of two unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the initial total energy (kinetic plus potential at 1m) equal to the final total energy (which will be entirely potential energy at height 2m)

There will only be *one* velocity, the initial velocity. There will be *two* heights.